# lets say I decide to write an application that manages to dos(tasks). what are the steps in preparing your work space in android studio to begin with?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependencies, android-developer-api

I have learned kotlin to a decent extent, I believe I can start making small applications. What is the best way to preapare your workspace on android studio. I mean things like dependencies, class files, kotlin files and so on. How does a programmer decide to divide his/her codes to different files.

I have tried to make a todo application and I find myself very confused on where to begin, what dependencies to use and how to organize my code properly.

Comment: Check out this google codelab for building an android to-do list app with firebase as a backend: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/build-android-app-with-firebase-compose?hl=en#1